# How to export JSON with py2neo?

Tags: python, json, neo4j, py2neo

I want to response the JSON which likes  exported from neo4j browser.
[image]
The structure like this.

```json
[
    {
        "p": {
            "start": {
                "identity": 2,
                "labels": [
                    "Person"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "born": 1964,
                    "name": "Keanu Reeves"
                }
            },
            "end": {
                "identity": 155,
                "labels": [
                    "Movie"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "title": "Something's Gotta Give",
                    "released": 2003
                }
            },
            "segments": [
                {
                    "start": {
                        "identity": 2,
                        "labels": [
                            "Person"
                        ],
                        "properties": {
                            "born": 1964,
                            "name": "Keanu Reeves"
                        }
                    },
                    "relationship": {
                        "identity": 221,
                        "start": 2,
                        "end": 155,
                        "type": "ACTED_IN",
                        "properties": {
                            "roles": [
                                "Julian Mercer"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "end": {
                        "identity": 155,
                        "labels": [
                            "Movie"
                        ],
                        "properties": {
                            "title": "Something's Gotta Give",
                            "released": 2003
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "length": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "p": {
            "start": {
                "identity": 2,
                "labels": [
                    "Person"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "born": 1964,
                    "name": "Keanu Reeves"
                }
            },
            "end": {
                "identity": 88,
                "labels": [
                    "Movie"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "tagline": "Pain heals, Chicks dig scars... Glory lasts forever",
                    "title": "The Replacements",
                    "released": 2000
                }
            },
            "segments": [
                {
                    "start": {
                        "identity": 2,
                        "labels": [
                            "Person"
                        ],
                        "properties": {
                            "born": 1964,
                            "name": "Keanu Reeves"
                        }
                    },
                    "relationship": {
                        "identity": 114,
                        "start": 2,
                        "end": 88,
                        "type": "ACTED_IN",
                        "properties": {
                            "roles": [
                                "Shane Falco"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "end": {
                        "identity": 88,
                        "labels": [
                            "Movie"
                        ],
                        "properties": {
                            "tagline": "Pain heals, Chicks dig scars... Glory lasts forever",
                            "title": "The Replacements",
                            "released": 2000
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "length": 1
        }
    }
]
```

In order to export json,I use the code like this:

```py
class JsonExtactor(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(JsonExtactor,self).__init__()
        self.graph = Graph(
            "http://localhost:7474",
            auth=('neo4j','neo4j'))
    def run(self):
        try:
            return(self.graph.run("MATCH p=()-[r:ACTED_IN]->() RETURN p LIMIT 2", {}).data())
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return None
JsonExtactor().run()
```

But it only returns a list like this:

> [{'p': Path(Node('Person', born=1964, name='Keanu Reeves'), ACTED_IN(Node('Person', born=1964, name='Keanu Reeves'), Node('Movie', released=2003, title="Something's Gotta Give")))}, {'p': Path(Node('Person', born=1964, name='Keanu Reeves'), ACTED_IN(Node('Person', born=1964, name='Keanu Reeves'), Node('Movie', released=2000, tagline='Pain heals, Chicks dig scars... Glory lasts forever', title='The Replacements')))}]

How to response the json format which is like above json structure ?

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38577005/outputiing-py2neo-query-as-json

Comment: I want export json as same as the file which is exported from browser.So it's not useful.Thank u